# Maneiras para verificação de tipo em javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando JavaScript, e me deparei com uma questão, que apresento abaixo, encontrei diversas maneiras de resolver um mesmo caso em JavaScript, e mostro a que escolhi. Gostaria de saber se conhecem outras maneiras, e como lidar melhor com esse tipo de situação, deixar o compilador trabalhar como fiz seria mesmo uma boa maneira de lidar com a questão ou estou equivocado?

```
// Utilizando a sintaxe de módulos, AssetPackage está
// em um arquivo diferente de PackageManager

function AssetPackage(name, assets) {
    this.name = name;
    this.assets = assets;
}

function PackageManager() {
    this.packages = {};
}
```

Não posso deixar objetos que não são pacotes serem adicionados
a packages, pois isso poderia fazer a API trabalhar mal. Imaginei os seguintes jeito de resolver isso:

Jeito 1 - instanceof

```
// Importo AssetPackage
PackageManager.prototype.addPackage = function(assetPackage) {
    if (!this.isAssetPackage(assetPackage))
      return false;

    this.packages[assetPackage.name] = assetPackage;
}

PackageManager.prototype.addPackages = function(assetPackages) {
    if (!this.isAssetPackage(assetPackage))
      return false;

    for(let i = 0; i < assetPackages.length; i++)
        this.packages[assetPackages[i].name] = assetPackages[i];
}

PackageManager.prototype.isAssetPackage = function(val) {
    return (val instanceof AssetPackage);
}
```

Jeito 2 - Verificando propriedades

```
// Não importo AssetPackage
PackageManager.prototype.addPackage = function(assetPackage) {
    if (!assetPackage.name || !assetPackage.assets)
        return false;

    this.packages[assetPackage.name] = assetPackage;
}

PackageManager.prototype.addPackages = function(assetPackages) {
    for(let i = 0; i < assetPackages.length; i++)
        if (!assetPackages.name || !assetPackages.assets)
            continue;
            this.packages[assetPackages[i].name] = assetPackages[i];
}
```

Jeito 3 - Verificando propriedades e atribuindo apenas elas

```
// Não importo AssetPackage
PackageManager.prototype.addPackage = function(assetPackage) {
    if (!assetPackage.name || !assetPackage.assets)
        return false;

    this.packages[assetPackage.name] = {
        name: assetPackage.name,
        assets: assetPackage.assets
    };
}

PackageManager.prototype.addPackages = function(assetPackages) {
    for(let i = 0; i < assetPackages.length; i++)
        if(!assetPackages.name || !assetPackages.assets)
            continue;
        this.packages[assetPackages[i].name] = {
            name: assetPackages[i].name,
            assets: assetPackages[i].assets
    };
}
```

Jeito 4 - Verificando propriedades e se é passado um objeto

```
// Não importo AssetPackage
PackageManager.prototype.addPackage = function(assetPackage) {
    if (!this.isObject(assetPackage) || !assetPackage.name || !assetPackage.assets)
        return false;

    this.packages[assetPackage.name] = {
        name: assetPackage.name,
        assets: assetPackage.assets
    };
}

PackageManager.prototype.addPackages = function(assetPackages) {
    if (!Array.isArray(assetPackages))
        return false;

    for(let i = 0; i < assetPackages.length; i++)
        if(!this.isObject(assetPackages) || !assetPackages[i].name || !assetPackages[i].assets)
            continue;
        this.packages[assetPackages[i].name] = {
            name: assetPackages[i].name,
            assets: assetPackages[i].assets
    };
}

PackageManager.prototype.isObject = function(val) {
    return (typeof val === "object" && val !== null);
}
```

Jeito 5 - constructor.name

```
PackageManager.prototype.addPackage = function(assetPackage) {
    if (!isAssetPackage(assetPackage))
      return false;

    this.packages[assetPackage.name] = assetPackage;
}

PackageManager.prototype.addPackages = function(assetPackages) {
    if (!isAssetPackage(assetPackage))
      return false;

    for(let i = 0; i < assetPackages.length; i++)
        this.packages[assetPackages[i].name] = assetPackages[i];
}

PackageManager.prototype.isAssetPackage = function(val) {
    return (getType(val) === 'AssetPackage');
}

PackageManager.prototype.getType = function (o) { 
    return o && o.constructor && o.constructor.name; 
}
```

Jeito 6 - O escolhido. Não fazer verificação alguma! deixe o compilador trabalhar.

```
// Importo AssetPackage
PackageManager.prototype.addPackage = function(assetPackage) {
    this.packages[assetPackage.name] = assetPackage.assets;
}

PackageManager.prototype.addPackages = function(assetPackages) {
    for(let i = 0; i < assetPackages.length; i++)
        this.packages[assetPackages[i].name] = assetPackages[i].assets;
}

// ou
PackageManager.prototype.addPackage = function(assetPackage) {
    this.packages[assetPackage.name] = {
      name: assetPackage.name,
      assets: assetPackage.assets
    };
}

PackageManager.prototype.addPackages = function(assetPackages) {
    for(let i = 0; i < assetPackages.length; i++)
        this.packages[assetPackages[i].name] = {
          name: assetPackages[i].name,
          assets: assetPackages[i].assets
        };
}
```

Eu escolhi deixar o compilador trabalhar pelos seguintes motivos, se eu retorno um "false" ou seja o que for retornar para o usuário da API, ele poderia simplesmente ignorar o false por desatenção, isso ocasionaria erros em seu código se não verificar corretamente o retorno das funções da API, já deixando o compilador trabalhar, o seu código simplesmente não compilaria e ele seria avisa com um erro, provavelmente de propriedade "undefined" ou coisa parecida, e um erro de compilação ele não consegue ignorar. Isso evitaria erros por descuido.

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar `throw`e especificar os erros? No momento que o seu código tentar acessar a esta propriedade o compilador vai lançar um `throw` de propriedade indefinida(undefined), com um simples debug o programador poderia encontrar(ou não kkk), personalizando e especificando com um `try...catch` pode facilitar a vida do sujeito.

Comment: @MSLacerda Na verdade acho que estava equivocado, o jeito 6 serviria para null e undefined, mas talvez seria melhor usar "instanceof", pois e se passo um objeto vazio ou array vazio? ou mesmo um objeto sem as propriedades que precisa ter, ele vai criar uma propriedade "undefined" em packages, e não quero isso. Mas poderia usar um throw também, crie uma resposta com sua maneira.

Comment: Hum, realmente pode haver esse problema, mas de qualquer forma esse erro iria estourar em algum lugar a frente, eu particularmente não gosto da ideia de retornar `false` (acho uma má prática nesse caso), mas vamos esperar se alguém tem uma resposta melhor...

Comment: @MSLacerda pensei em mais uma, um pato misturado com console.error kkkkkkk `if (!this.isObject(assetPackage) || !assetPackage.name || !assetPackage.assets)
        return console.error('You must pass an AssetPackage as an argument to addPackage.');` kkkkk Claro q n deve fazer isso kkkk Mas talvez apenas retornar um false mesmo seja melhor.

Comment: @MSLacerda Uma solução melhor então é usar throw como vc disse, mas não precisamos de try/catch aqui: `if (!this.isObject(assetPackage) || !assetPackage.name || !assetPackage.assets)
        throw new TypeError('You must pass an AssetPackage as an argument to addPackage.');`

Comment: Eu acho que você está se perdendo por tentar usar uma linguagem não tipada como se fosse tipada.

Comment: @bfavaretto sinto isso, mas qual é a outra forma de lidar com o mesmo caso mais adequada ao JavaScript? seria simplesmente não fazer verificação nenhuma?